# Align a pointer

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

I want to align a pointer p so that `p = a (modulo b)`. Most of the time, a = 0 and b = 32 or 64 for SIMD alignement, but I might also want a = 64 and b = 128 when I want to fine tune my algorithm for cache associativity.

- `std::align` does not accept any power of 2 for alignement. It will be fixed in C++17, but it is useless right now
- `__mm_malloc/__free` is not as portable as I want

My best solution so far is to cast the pointer to a `std::uintptr_t` and use modulo operations on integers to move the pointer. Unfortunately, it is not portable as casting a pointer to `std::uintptr_t` is not "allowed". But it works on all platforms I have tried so far.

On what kind of platform would such a code break?

Comment: std::align does not yet accept any power of 2. It will work on C++17 : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align

Answer (score 2):

Might be you look for something like this:

```
inline size_t AlignHi(size_t size, size_t align)
{
    return (size + align - 1) & ~(align - 1);
}

inline void * Allocate(size_t size, size_t align)
{
#if defined(_MSC_VER) 
    return _aligned_malloc(size, align);
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    align = AlignHi(align, sizeof(void*));
    size = AlignHi(size, align);
    void * ptr;
    int result = ::posix_memalign(&ptr, align, size);
    return result ? NULL : ptr;
#else
    return malloc(size);
#endif
}

inline void Free(void * p)
{
#if defined(_MSC_VER) 
    _aligned_free(p);
#else
    free(p);
#endif
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something more "universal". But it seems to be the only correct way of doing it right now.

Comment: I took these functions from cross platform SIMD library.

Answer (score 1):

The following C++ code requires that `alignment` is a power of 2.  Memory allocated wit `malloc_aligned` must be released with `free_aligned`:

```
void *
malloc_aligned(std::size_t alignment, std::size_t size)
{
    alignment = std::max(alignment, alignof(void *));
    size     += alignment;

    void *ptr  = std::malloc(size);
    void *ptr2 = (void *)(((uintptr_t)ptr + alignment) & ~(alignment-1));
    void **vp  = (void**) ptr2 - 1;
    *vp        = ptr;
    return ptr2;
}

void
free_aligned(void *ptr)
{
    std::free(*((void**)ptr-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> std::align does not accept any power of 2 for alignement. I will be fixed in C++17, but it is useless right now

Let's see what the standard (draft) says.

> **[ptr.align]**
>
> 2 Requires:
>
> (2.1) — alignment shall be a fundamental alignment value or an extended alignment value supported by the implementation in this context.

So, any fundamental alignment value is allowed, and possibly others if allowed by the implementation. Let's see what a fundamental alignment is.

> **[basic.align]**
>
> 2 A **fundamental alignment** is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to alignof(std::max_align_t)...

Ok. Then there is a limitation to all alignments.

> 4 Alignments are represented as values of the type std::size_t. Valid alignments include only those values returned by an alignof expression for the fundamental types plus an additional implementation-defined set of values, which may be empty. **Every alignment value** shall be a non-negative integral **power of two**.

So, not only are power of 2 alignments allowed, but in fact *only* powers of 2 alignments are allowed. The difference with C++17 is that until then, only alignments less than or equal to `alignof(std::max_align_t)` (i.e. fundamental alignments) are allowed. Support for bigger alignment depends on implementation.

TL;DR Your premise is wrong. But whether `std::align` works, is still implementation defined until C++17.

Comment: Thanks for your careful explanation. But alignof(std::max_align_t) is 16 on many platform. It is below SIMD sizes : 32 or 64.

Comment: @InsideLoop fair enough. I guess there is no standard way to get an alignment of 32 or 64 bytes until C++17. I'll leave my answer for completeness, if you don't mind.